# Multiple Condition Coverage - Larger Example

Tags: unit-testing, testing, multiple-conditions

In Multiple Condition Coverage, what would the required number of test cases for the below program be, for full coverage?

```
int foo(bool a, bool b, bool c, bool d) {
    if (a && b) {
        print("Hi");
    }
    if (c && d) {
        print("Hi");
    }
}
```

I know it's either 16 or 8, but I'm not sure which. Do I only test all combinations of inputs within the respective if statements, or the overall program? Because if it's the overall program, that's going to be a *lot* of test cases in a large program...

Answer (score 0):

It's 8, per the definitions of these on Wikipedia.